# Maximum number of acute interior angles in a hexagon.

Tags: geometry

Is it possible for a hexagon (in the plane, non-convex, non-overlapping) to have $5$ acute interior angles?  It's possible for a pentagon or a hexagon to have $4$ acute interior angles.  There are related questions on this site, but they are for general $n$-gons and no one seems to have a definitive answer.  So what about just 6-gons?

Want to know what I tried?  Fine, I wore out 3 Expo markers on my whiteboard trying stuff.

Comment: The sum of interior angles is $720$. So if $4$ are acute angles, they sum to $\lt 360$. Then the rest two must sum to $\gt 360$. So  it cannot be a convex hexagon.

Comment: @MathLover I said "non-convex."

Comment: yes it cannot be convex but can surely be non-convex. That is what I tried to explain. You can draw one in Geo-Gebra and confirm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to have $5$; see this figure for an example.  You can easily formalize the argument once you see it; I have left that as an exercise.

[image]