# What is the maximum no. of acute angles in a n-sided convex polygon?

Tags: combinatorics

This question is from permutations and combinations i have no approaches it would be fine if someone could just give an approach to this problem.
I am a high school student with basic knowledge of combinatorics

Comment: Try starting with small cases. What’s the maximum number of acute angles in a triangle? What’s the maximum number of acute angles in a convex quadrilateral? Convex pentagon?

Comment: The external angle next to an acute angle is in $(90^\circ, 180^\circ)$. The sum of all external angles of a polygon is $360^\circ$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @peterwhy noticed in the comments, the sum of external angles of a convex polygon is $360^\circ$ and an external angle corresponding to internal acute angle is greater than $90^\circ$. Thus any convex polygon cannot have more than three external obtuse angles and, correspondingly, more than three acute internal angles.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4258477/362009